# "Harry enjoys traveling around" vs. "Harry enjoys to travel around"

Tags: grammar

> Harry enjoys traveling around.

Why can't I use "to travel" instead of "traveling"?

I heard that **"Harry enjoys to travel around"** is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

There are some verbs that always take gerund form. Some of those are enjoy, avoid etc.

Therefore

> Harry enjoys traveling around.

Is correct

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *Harry enjoys traveling around*.
>
> [2]* *Harry enjoys to travel around*.

"Enjoy" is here a catenative verb (one that takes a non-finite clause as complement), but it only licenses (permits) gerund-participial clauses as complement, not infinitival ones.

Thus [1] is fine but [2] is ungrammatical.